# Hide System Bar on Android 5.0

Tags: android, root

I was using this code to hide the system bar

```
 try {
      Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity " + 42
        + " s16 com.android.systemui"});
      process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But since the 5.0 update this code doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following. 
Put the system bar in "lights out" mode, the system bar buttons and notifications gets dimmed.

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted add this to /system/build.prop

```
ro.statusbar.alwayshide=true
```

and reboot device